# bg-info doesn't work for the whole body in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code and I am not sure why bg-info doesn't work for the whole body as I am new to bootstrap.

```
<!--http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body class="bg-info">
<div class="container text-xs-center">
    <h1 class="display-1">Fullstack Conference</h1>
    <p class="lead">Coming soon!! A one day conference about all things Javascript!!</p>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Email for info...">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Sign Up!</button>
      </span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery first, then Bootstrap JS. -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's what I see:
[image]

Note: According to this video it should work though https://teamtreehouse.com/library/bootstrap-4-basics/getting-to-know-bootstrap-4/enhancing-the-page

Comment: share your css as if i run only this html its bg cover whole page.

Comment: there is no CSS. This is the only file I have (.html) it is using twitter bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the alpha 4 of bootstrap(js), use bootstrap 3.x.

Also you have an extra `</div>` in the code.

This works:

```html
<!--http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body class="bg-info">
  <div class="container text-xs-center">
    <h1 class="display-1">Fullstack Conference</h1>
    <p class="lead">Coming soon!! A one day conference about all things Javascript!!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Email for info...">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Sign Up!</button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>


  <!-- jQuery first, then Bootstrap JS. -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for catching it. The problem was with extra div. Why shouldn't I use the current version? The instructor is using the same exact version.

Comment: @MonaJalal Its generally advised not to use alpha versions as they may have issues which are yet to be fixed. I would suggest use of a stable version. (Also currently BS4 aplha JS throws an exception when you use it.)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by doesn't work for the whole body? Try to add this CSS property to your custom CSS:

```
.bg-info {background: #5bc0de!important;
  }
```